# Difference between += and =+ in C++

Tags: c++, operators

While programming in C++, I often confuse both "+=" and "=+", the former being the operator I actually mean. Visual Studio seems to accept both, yet they behave differently and is a source for a lot of my bugs. I know that a += b is semantically equivalent to a = a+b, but what does "=+" do?

Comment: As people have answered, you should use `+=` and not `=+`. If you find yourself frequently doing that mistake, just write a checklist of things you need to find in files and fix periodically (before releasing). `=+` would be one of these things. You could also add usual typos - `lenght` for `length`, bad formatting - `if(` for `if (`, etc. to the list.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`=+` is really `= +` (assignment and the unary `+` operators).

In order to help you remember `+=`, remember that it does addition first, then assignment. Of course that depends on the actual implementation, but it should be for the primitives.

Answer (score 17):

`a =+ b` means `a = +b` means `a = b`

Comment: unless the unary `+` is overloaded.

Comment: unless `b` is an integer type smaller than `int`, in which case it promotes `b` to `int` as well as doing the assignment.

Answer (score 6):

if you see `=` the first , it means you re-declare your variable value , 
but if you face `+` the first it means that you order the compiler to increment the value of the variable   , keep it in you mind

```
int x=20 ;
x=+10 ;
cout<< x <<endl ; // x  = 10


x+=10 ;
cout<< x<<endl ; // x= 10+10 = 20
```

Answer (score -1):

I may be remembering this wrong, but I think that in C, C++, and even Java (which has similar syntax to C and C++), =+ and += actually behave very similarly. The statement that =+ is assignment (equivalent to plain = operator), while += increases a variable's value by a certain amount, is INCORRECT.

x += y as well as x =+ y will BOTH have the same effect (that is, both of these will cause the new value of x to be the old value of x + y). The difference comes in when you have a slightly more complex expression.

z = (x += y) and z = (x =+ y) will have DIFFERENT outputs for the variable z.
Let's look at each one of these:

z = (x += y) will add y to x, and then set z to be the NEW value of x.

z = (x =+ y) will set z to be the OLD value of x, and then add y to x.

It's possible I got those 2 backwards, but I do remember reading somewhere before that the differences I describe here are the ACTUAL differences between those 2.

Comment: You are remembering very wrongly. `z =+ x` is parsed out as `z = (+x)`, that is, unary `+` of `x`. If `x` is an int, the `+` has no effect.